# Keep only first occurrence of elements in a list

Tags: python

how can i delete the last duplicate Element in a list.

For example: `a = [1,2,4,5,1,3,5,6]`

I try to delete Element #6 and Element #4. But im just able to delete #1 and #4.

Is it also possible, to delete all duplicates with a higher index than the first one? e.g. `a = [ 1,2,1,3,1,4,5]` --> Delete #2,#4

Comment: I'd really like to help but I have no idea what you're talking about. When you say "Element #6" do you mean, specifically, the **sixth** element, or the element whose value is **6**?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read the [tour] which was suggested when you registered, and browse the [Help]. If you wrote some code but it did not work, better add it to your post.

Comment: Once you delete one element, the size of the list changes and hence the indices also change. So the 4th index before deleting one element will be 3rd index after deleting. This applies to all the indices

Comment: @nixon Just curious what is manual iteration? If you are referring to a `for` loop is being manual process then so is importing a numpy library. Just saying

Comment: Well @mad_ disregard the "manual", I'm obviousle refering to a for loop

Answer (score 0):

Start off with simple iteration and filter off if you have seen the element before

```
a=[1,2,4,5,1,3,5,6]

def removeDuplicates(listofElements):
    uniqueList = []
    for elem in listofElements:
        if elem not in uniqueList:
            uniqueList.append(elem)

    return uniqueList

removeDuplicates(a)
```

Obviously, no hard feeling for `numpy` but it will not be efficient in these problems which can be solved by mere iteration

```
from timeit import timeit
def use_numpy(a):
    x, ix = np.unique(a, return_index=True)
    np.array(a)[sorted(ix)].tolist()
```

The above code is taken from the answer posted by @nixon

```
print(timeit('use_numpy(a)',setup='from __main__ import use_numpy; import numpy as np;a = [1,2,4,5,1,3,5,6]',number=1000000))
print(timeit('removeDuplicates(a)',setup='from __main__ import removeDuplicates; import numpy as np;a = [1,2,4,5,1,3,5,6]',number=1000000))
```

**Output**

```
14.6761189173  # numpy
1.08678438189  # for loop
```

Answer (score 0):

with pandas, you can drop duplicates and pass in the argument to either keep the first or last instance, then convert it to a list:

```
import pandas as pd

a = [1,2,4,5,1,3,5,6]

df = pd.DataFrame(a, columns=['a'])

a_keep_first = list(df.drop_duplicates(keep="first")['a'])
print (a_keep_first)
# output: [1, 2, 4, 5, 3, 6]


a_keep_last = list(df.drop_duplicates(keep="last")['a'])
print (a_keep_last)
# output: [2, 4, 1, 3, 5, 6]
```

However, this is assuming you want NO duplicates. it raises another question of what if there are more than 2 duplicates? so if you want to drop the last duplicate (if there are 3 duplicates), does that mean you're left with 2 duplicates?

given: `a = [1,2,4,5,1,3,5,6,1]`

do you want: `a = [1,2,4,5,1,3,6]` or `a = [1,2,4,5,3,6,]` ?

Answer (score 0):

Here's two basic ways you can do it.
First is taking advantage of sets being unique, but notice that the order is not kept.
Second way maintains the order.

```
list_num = [1,2,1,3,1,4,5]
unique_set = set(); # sets don't allow duplicates
for n in list_num:
    unique_set.add(n)    
unique_list_1 = list(unique_set)


unique_list_2 = []
for n in list_num:
    if n not in unique_list_2:
        unique_list_2.append(n)
```

Comment: This may not solve if list contains unhashable data types. Request you to update the answer